# How to optimise master-slave query with count by max?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to get games with current number of players for each of game ordered by the measure of what percent of player slots are filled by players.

It goes like this:

```
SELECT 
  g.* , COUNT( p.ID ) NUM_OF_PLAYERS 
FROM 
  games g, 
  players p
WHERE  
  g.ID = p.GAME_ID 
GROUP BY 
  g.ID 
ORDER BY 
  COUNT( p.ID ) / g.MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS DESC
```

And it takes like 4 seconds.

And Explain gives me this mainly:

[image]

How to make it faster?

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT( p.ID ) / MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS DESC` what is this? Is `MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS` constant?

Comment: MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS is column in games table

Comment: I have index on p.GAME_ID

Comment: It's inner join. It's good here

Comment: You're right that the old style join will optimize just as well as inner join in the FROM clause.  The problem is that you are doing an order by with an expression.  The database has to get every record, grouped by the game id (you might try your query with group by p.GAME_ID), but then has to sort the result.  To sort it has to load the whole result set in memory, and run a sort algorithm which at best might be n*log(n) order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. Is it faster?

```
select g.*,p.NUM_OF_PLAYERS NUM_OF_PLAYERS 
from games g
left join 
(
select GAME_ID, COUNT( ID ) NUM_OF_PLAYERS 
  from players group by GAME_ID
) p on (g.ID = p.GAME_ID)

ORDER BY 
  p.NUM_OF_PLAYERS/g.MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS DESC
```

Comment: Add an index on to `players.Game_id` and change the inner select to `count(*)`.